# Simulink cross correlation issue

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation, simulink

here is the Simulink model that i'm using :
[image]

The matlab function script :

```
function tau = fcn(sig,refsig)

tau = gccphat(sig,refsig);
```

The errors :

[image]